# Why .filter() in Marionette.CollectionView doesn't work?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Why .filter() in Marionette.CollectionView doesn't work?
It just isn't fired.

P.S. Collection has one element.

1 file:

```
  documents = new Collections.Documents
  documents.fetch().done =>
    @getRegion('certificates').show(new Views.CertificatesCollectionView(documents))
    @getRegion('diplomas').show(new Views.DiplomasCollectionView(documents))
```

2 file:

```
class Views.DiplomasCollectionView extends Marionette.CollectionView

  initialize: (@collection) ->
    console.log 'intzd'
  childView: Views.DocumentItemView

  filter: (document_model) ->
    console.log 'fitr'
    document_model.is_diploma()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

`@getRegion('diplomas').show(new Views.DiplomasCollectionView(collection: documents))`

and

```
class Views.DiplomasCollectionView extends Marionette.CollectionView
  childView: Views.DocumentItemView

  filter: (document_model) ->
    console.log 'fitr'
    document_model.is_diploma()
```